# formatting different kind of float numbers as original format with python

Tags: python, formatting

I am selecting Oracle data with python/cx_Oracle and inserting into Impala with same field types

I have number field in Oracle table and sample data of it like that

```
0.1428571428571428571428571428571428571429
0
0.2111
2.1
0.04
```

So I am trying to create sql string to execute insert data into Impala like that

```
sql4Impala = "insert into test01.ornek_2 values (%f, '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')" % (row[0], row[1], row[2], row [3], row[4])
```

My problem is starting here I don't know what kind of real number selected from oracle side. So could not format the number as original format

For example

```
0.0344827586207 it's original data
0.034483        automatically trimed out with %f
```

So how can I format the real number in sql4Impala while I don't know the original data's format

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you fetch the data directly you will get back floating point numbers, which do not have the same precision as the Oracle numbers stored in the database. To get around this, retrieve the data as strings and then use decimal.Decimal(value) instead. Like this:

```
connection = cx_Oracle.connect("user/pw@tns")
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("select to_char(some_number) from some_table")
for rawNumber, in cursor:
    number = decimal.Decimal(rawNumber)
```